# Suppress quotes in stdout (hackerrank)

Tags: haskell, io, stdout, double-quotes

I'm working on a [string compression problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-compression/problem) in Hackerrank in Haskell, and stuck on the IO.  I am trying to be explicit about removing quotes.

```
compress :: [Char] -> [Char]
compress = ...

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- getLine
    let result = compress input
    print $ filter (/='"') result
```

The code compiles and returns the correct response, albeit surrounded in quotes.

```
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer

Input (stdin)
abcaaabbb

Your Output (stdout)
"abca3b3"

Expected Output
abca3b3
```

Comment: The quotes are not in the *content* of the string. These are in the *representation* of the string, since `print` calls `show`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You write:

```
putStrLn result
```

instead of last line:

```
 print $ filter (/='"') result
```